# Mercurial for small scale research team

Tags: windows, mercurial

Our team consists of 3 people and we want to use Mercurial for the verison control of our codes.

The problem is that we don't have a common server that we all have access to.

Is there a way to make one of the users the host of the repository, so that others can connect him to work on the code?

We're all using Windows 7, if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just run `hg serve` in that host & directory. If you have IP access you'll be able to work with it. You'll need to set the `web.allow_push` option to `*` to enable the remote push.

Another option is to run `hg serve` on all the workstations and only pull from one another, never push.

Answer (score 4):

Because mercurial is a distributed version control system, you don't have to have a central server, as you can clone, push and pull between one another.
But, you could look at creating a central repository on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) at no cost for up to 5 users.